# All combination date differences in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, date, adjacency-matrix

I have the following dataframes with many dates. I want to:

```
sales_agents["hire_date"]


  0    2017-04-01 00:00:00

  1    2017-05-03 00:00:00

  2    2017-10-17 00:00:00

  Name: hire_date, dtype: object
```

I would like to obtain the difference in DAYS from row 0 to row n:

```
output = [(2017-04-01 - 2017-05-03), (2017-04-01 - 2017-10-17), (2017-05-03 - 2017-10-17)]
```

The result should be in DAYS and I want to get the difference of all possible combinations except itself.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do a `'cross'` merge and use the index to filter to basically the upper triangle so that you don't double double count AB and BA merges (row1 with row 2 and row 2 with row 1), and also exclude AA merges (row 1 merging with itself).

The result then shows you the difference, in days, as well as the two dates used to form that difference. If you want to keep a record of where those dates came from you can remove the `.drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y'])` part of the code.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-04-01 00:00:00', '2017-05-03 00:00:00', 
                            '2017-10-17 00:00:00']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

#### Code

```
res = (pd.merge(df[['date']].reset_index(), df[['date']].reset_index(), how='cross')
         .query('index_x > index_y')
         .drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y']))

res['diff'] = (res['date_y'] - res['date_x']).dt.days

print(res)
#      date_x     date_y  diff
#3 2017-05-03 2017-04-01   -32
#6 2017-10-17 2017-04-01  -199
#7 2017-10-17 2017-05-03  -167
```

---

Alternatively you can do this in numpy using an outer subtraction and then you extract the lower triangle of values (excluding the diagonal `k=1`). Since these are calculated in nanoseconds, we then need to convert into days by the factor of `10**9*60*60*24`

```
import numpy as np

arr = df['date'].to_numpy()[:, None] - df['date'].to_numpy()[None, :]
days = arr[np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0], k=1)]/(10**9*60*60*24)

days
#array([ -32, -199, -167], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

Comment: Your pandas solution is great. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Could do a an adjacency matrix using cross merge and numpy outer subtract. Code below

```
g, h = df.merge(df, how='cross').to_numpy().T
g=np.unique(g)
h=np.unique(h)

pd.DataFrame(np.subtract.outer(g, g), h, h) 

    

             2017-04-01 2017-05-03 2017-10-17
2017-04-01     0 days   -32 days  -199 days
2017-05-03    32 days     0 days  -167 days
2017-10-17   199 days   167 days     0 days
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It helps indeed. I am getting error on the function np.subtract.outer as NotImplementedError:

Comment: What version are you on, works flawlessly this end

Comment: I am using this version : '1.20.3'